# Can one carry a pocket knife on shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, muktzeh, utensil

If one is used to carrying a pocket knife during the week, is it ok to carry one on shabbat?

For some more background, assume it is a spring-assisted or "button knife" but not generally something people would repair on the fly, so shouldn't be worried that it would be repaired if broken on shabbat.

Second, would it make a difference if it was purchased separately, and isn't used during the week? Or if it is toveled and can be used for food too?

Assume there's an eruv; this is a question of muktzah.

Comment: Is it something they do as a habit or due to a danger?

Comment: Similar - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59832/can-one-use-a-swiss-army-knife-on-shabbat

Comment: @Chatzkel it's done for both, habit and danger. That similar post doesn't really answer the question, that one more delves into the issue of using muktza items with parts that are not meant to use on shabbos. Unless you infer from it that you can just carry a knife that isn't anything but a knife....

Comment: @thethinkingyid yes that’s exactly what I would infer from that. In fact many hold that as long as part of it is useable it’s not muktzah. https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-23-08/